# Try to solve Binomial Distribution

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I just got a problem related to binomial distribution as following.

Which value of $k$ makes $\left(\begin{matrix}n \\ k\end{matrix} \right)p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ as large as possible?

I've spend hours on this question but have no idea how to calculate the derivative for factorial. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The expectation of the distribution? How could we prove it?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52222.html should help. Their answer is a lot clearer than mine!

Comment: I understand it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @OldPanda : This is not about the expectation.  The value of $k$ are $0,1,2,\ldots,n$, but the expectation doesn't have to be one of those.  The expectation is $np$.  What is sought is the mode, not the expectation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you! I did the [process](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52222.html) myself. Now I can understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the terms be $t_k = {n \choose k } p^k (1-p)^{n - k}$.

**Hint:** Consider the ratio $ \frac{ t_k} { t_{k-1} } $. When is this more than 1? When is this less than 1?